# Section titles: single, centered roman numerals

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, roman-numerals

As the title suggests, I want my section titles to be single, centered roman numerals. That's it, no actual section names.

Is that possible? If so, how might I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Which  document class do you use? Shall all section titles be centered,numberless etc, i.e. `\subsection` etc. too? How should they appear in the ToC? Numbered lines without any text? What about starred `\section*`? -- they do not even have a number!

Comment: Hi ! take a look on the titlesec package [https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec]

Comment: Thank you! Article class. I'm only using '\section', no other sectioning command. No ToC. Something like \section*{I} might help, but I'm still having trouble getting it centered and an appropriate size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet in `\@sect` (see the LaTeX format file `latex.ltx`)

```
#6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
```

is basically responsible for typesetting the section number and section title. `#6` is actually a command from `\@startsection` and is related to font settings. 
`\@svsec` will do `\the...` effectively, i.e. the section number.

This has to be removed from the standard definition be replaced by

```
\centering 

#6{\sv@sec}%
```

Please note, that this would change any of the `\section...` commands and would leave entries in the ToC as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
     \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
}{%
    \begingroup
    \centering 

    #6{\@svsec}%

    \endgroup
}{\typeout{Works}}{\typeout{Fails!}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\blindtext
\section{Second}
\blindtext
\section{}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick followup. When you add a title, author, and date to what you've got, it looks as though either the title or the section numbers are not perfectly centered. Not a big deal at all, but do you know why that is?

Comment: @go_humble: Yes, my lazyness! I've forgot to add a `%` after `#6{\@svsec}%`

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the "patching" of the `\@sect` macro can be accomplished not only with the `\xpatchcmd` macro of the `xpatch` package, but also with the `\patchcmd` macro of the `etoolbox` package. The syntax of the `\patchcmd` and `\xpatchcmd` macros is the same, i.e., both macros take the same four arguments.

Comment: @Mico: That's true of course, but `xpatch` uses `etoolbox` already and replacing it here by `etoolbox` would not diminish the number of included packages. (I could of  couse use brute force and `\def\@sect` to get rid of any other package (apart from `blindtext`)

Comment: I'm afraid I must not have expressed myself sufficiently clearly. I did *not* mean to criticize your answer. I only wanted to point out that in addition to the method you describe in your answer, there's also another method (which, unsurprisingly, uses a different package). Just in case a user happens to be familiar with the `etoolbox` package, he/she may wish to proceed using that package and its `\patchcmd` macro.